# creating provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I want to test my Xcode project at my device (iPhone 5s, IOS 10.2) for free (without paying 99$). I don't want send my projects to App Store.
I went to developer.apple.com and created Apple ID. Then I opened Xcode, created a new project, went to Preferences and Added my created Apple ID. But Provisioning Profile doesn't created.
In "Keychain Access" when I tab to certificate, I see the red inscription: "This certificate was signed by an unknown Bureau".
How can I solve this question? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing Apple's Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority (WWDRCA), located [here](http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer). Download and install that on your Mac and give it another shot.

Comment: YYYEEEEAAHH!!)) You were right! I downloaded this certificate and copied it to directory: /Library/Application Support/JAMF
must create folder "JAMF" if it absent)

Comment: Glad it helped.